# Table data and horizontal rule spacing

Tags: html, css

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/haWd5/) .
How can I assign the Horizontal rule to the top ? Means it should touch/overlap the table border.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's you want http://jsfiddle.net/haWd5/1/ ?. Write like this:

```
hr{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
td{vertical-align:top;}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/haWd5/2/

hr TAG SHOULD `MARGIN:0 ;  PADDING : 0`